# HTML CSS z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have two dropdowns as in following example:

Hover over first dropdown, and 2nd's text is still visible. Why?

https://jsfiddle.net/tnt7dxq2/

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropbtn">
      <a>dropdown!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a class="firstA" href="#">Item1</a>
        <a href="#">Item2</a>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
</p>
<div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropbtn">
      <a>dropdown!</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a class="firstA" href="#">Item1</a>
        <a href="#">Item2</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add a positive z-index on the CSS rule for `.dropdown-content`. More importantly, please include your code in your question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not define any `z-index`...

See this update of your fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/tnt7dxq2/1/

Is this what you wanted ?
I only added `z-index:2;` to your CSS `.dropdown-content {`.

Comment: Thanks for the green check! ;) NOTICE that I added `z-index:2;`... But `z-index:1;` would have been ok. Higher is the `z-index`, most on top is the element. By default when not specified, `z-index` = 0. You can play with negative `z-index` too. ;) Cheers!